# X-ray production rate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, x-rays

A 100 MeV proton beam of $10^{14}$ proton/s is perpendicularly incident on a rhodium foil 25 $\mu$m in thickness. Estimate the production rate of K and L x-rays(use the figure below).

---

[image]

---

So far I figured out from above the cross section for L x-rays to be $8\times 10^{2}$ barns and for  K x-rays to be $1\times 10^{2}$ barns

I have the right answers for this one but I can't seem to figure out the right formula to use in order to arrive the given answer.

L $1.3\times10^{13}$ per second
K $1.6\times10^{12}$ per second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this homework problem, you need to find the number of nuclei per barn in the foil.

If you read [The Value of the Cross-Section Concept](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/crosec2.html)
 you will understand what to do.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out now. I'll make sure to give you points when I get at least 15 reputation points.